# how to properly update submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

We have submodules in our project. Here is our current workflow to update these submodules

```
git pull
git pull --recurse-submodules
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

is it necessary to do `git pull --recurse-submodules` when git pull does the work for us?

What's the proper way to update submodules (to the version that the main project knows about) after pulling (doing a git pull) and doing a git clone.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've changed your configuration, you don't need to call `git pull --recurse-submodules`. From [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> **fetch.recurseSubmodules**
>
> When set to *on-demand* (the default value), fetch and pull will only recurse into a populated submodule when its superproject retrieves a commit that updates the submodule’s reference.

You do still need to call `git submodule update` after the `pull`. `--init` is only required if there's a new submodule, but doesn't hurt to run every time. Similarly, `--recursive` is only needed if your submodules have their own submodules, but also does no harm.